# floating schema definition of table - how to in pl/sql

Tags: postgresql

I’m new to pl/SQL and would like to get some advice on whether this code snippet could be written in a more generic way.
What I mean by general is that I may get the new ‘source data’, in which the schema may vary. For example, what is currently available as:
name_1, name_2, lakename_1 in other ‘source data’ might be available under different names, and the number of the column might be also different.
Ideally would be to have one section of the code in which the names of columns could be defined. This is probably where pl/SQL come into the action.
Thank you in advance for assistance with it.

```
SELECT


    nid,
    name_1,
    name_2,
    lakename_1,
    lakename_2,
    rivname_1,
    rivname_2,  

    concat_ws(',', "name_1", "name_2", "lakename_1", "lakename_2", "rivname_1", "rivname_2" ) concated_names,
    ---number of names
    (
        (CASE WHEN name_1 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer +
        (CASE WHEN name_2 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer +
        (CASE WHEN lakename_1 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer +
        (CASE WHEN lakename_2 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer +
        (CASE WHEN rivname_1 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer +
        (CASE WHEN rivname_2 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer
    ) number_of_names,



    ---unique combinations of names occurence
    (
        (CASE WHEN name_1 != '' THEN 'name1' ELSE '' END) || ',' ||
        (CASE WHEN name_2 != '' THEN 'name2' ELSE '' END) || ',' ||
        (CASE WHEN lakename_1 != '' THEN 'lakename_1' ELSE '' END) || ',' ||
        (CASE WHEN lakename_2 != '' THEN 'lakename_2' ELSE '' END) || ',' ||
        (CASE WHEN rivname_1 != '' THEN 'rivname_1' ELSE '' END) || ',' ||
        (CASE WHEN rivname_2 != '' THEN 'rivname_2' ELSE '' END) 
    ) unique_names

    ,

    geom 

    INTO canada_merged.number_of_names_per_features

FROM
    canada_merged.waterbody_and_waterlines
    where name_1 !=''
    or name_2 !=''
    or lakename_1 !=''
    or lakename_2 !=''
    or rivname_1 !=''
    or rivname_2 !='';
```

Comment: PL/SQL is a procedural language specific to the Oracle database. Postgres has many different procedural languages (for writing stored functions and procedures) one of them is named PL/pgSQL. But your question only contains plain SQL - are you looking to write a stored function or procedure?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(CASE WHEN name_1 != '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)::integer` can be simplified to `(CASE WHEN name_1 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry for being not precise. I thought about PL/pgSQL. Considering my case  and looking into [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_procedures.htm) I would say I'm more interested about wrapping is as procedure. There will be a process set up before starting the converion and at that point one should have the possibility to define the column names specific for given 'source data. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yoz need dynamic SQL.